# How can I check if timestamp is greater than current time (without reloading page) in JS/Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a website using Vue.js and am trying to highlight a row if the `item.queue_entry_time > (NOW - 1 hour)`

The `queue` is an array of objects that have following attributes

```
queue_entry_time
queue_call_time
queue_entrant_name
```

Markup

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in queue">
  <div class="">
  </div>
</template>
```

What I'm trying to do is display `class1` in my div when the condition above is met. I'm not sure how to do this as creating a function to return the current timestamp is fixed and won't change as the time progresses.

Comment: so, you'll want a setInterval running - updating some `data:` value that's used in the highlight logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a Boolean attribute to the object (e.g., named `recent`) that is [periodically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) set based on its `queue_entry_time`:

```js
export default {
  //...
  mounted() {
    this._timer = setInterval(() => {
      const anHourAgo = Date.now() - (60 * 60 * 1000)
      for (const q of this.queue) {
        q.recent = q.queue_entry_time > anHourAgo
      }
    }, 5000)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this._timer)
  },
}
```

Then, use [conditional rendering](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#conditional-rendering) based on each object's `recent` to show `class1`:

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in queue">
  <div v-if="item.recent">class1</div>
</template>
```

If you actually meant you wanted to apply a class based on this condition, you could use a [class binding](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax):

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in queue">
  <div :class="{ class1: item.recent }">...</div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/periodic-class-binding-vtv2s?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)

Comment: never looked into class (and style) binding before - that really simplifies some of my (bad) code!!

Answer (score 1):

set your markup as follows

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in queue">
    <div :class="{class1: checkCutoff(item)}">
    
    </div>
</template>
```

Then you'll need to

- add a property to your `data` to hold cutoff
- add a `method` called by `:class`
- add code to `mounted` to start an interval
- add code to `beforeDestroy` to stop the interval

so, like this:

```
data: () => ({
    cutoff: 0
}),
methods: {
    checkCutoff(item) {
        return item.queue_entry_time > cutoff;
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.cutoff = new Date - 60 * 60 * 1000, 1000);
},
beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: No need to make `interval` a data prop, as it doesn't need to be reactive.

Comment: true - I always mess that up :p